# Can I post the same question to multiple community, i.e. stackoverflow and serverfault?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, cross-posting

When asking question about `collectd` I was confused, as to where do I ask this question, stackoverflow or serverfault, because both communities are discussing this topic.

Is there any ways for sharing some questions to multiple communities and get inputs/answers?

Comment: No. Select the single site where your question is most appropriate and stick to it. Don't cross-post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. As a matter of fact, I simply forgot search meta first. I had other similar question, and I found the answers to them.

Answer (score 0):

Same question? No.

But you can probably ask separate questions, that touches the same area:

- *ServerFault*: How to configure ....... to collect data ......?
- *StackOverflow*: How to process this data to calculate ......?

Same topic all right, but different questions.

Note: Examples are oversimplified of course and I know that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All I was trying to suggest is that I am loosing on to get inputs from pros in other communities if my judgement call is wrong.